# Reading odd dimensions

Tags: electrical-engineering, unit

I am reading a paper and the dimensions for some electrodes are given, but I was wondering if I was reading it properly:

**30 × 15 mm<sup>2</sup>**, is this the same as: **(30 × 15)mm<sup>2</sup>** ?

To track the published paper I provide below its Digital Object Identifier (DOI) commonly used in online research papers. This number should lead you directly to the paper.

DOI: 10.1002/aesr.202000093

Comment: those measurements actually make no sense

Comment: "Both electrodes were cut in dimensions of 30x15mm2." This is word by word what is stated on the article.

Comment: `30×15 mm2` may be 30 something long with 15 mm2 cross section .... `(30×15) mm2` could just mean 450 mm2 cross section, no stated length

Comment: Yeah, I am not sure how to interpret it either. As you said, it could be interpreted in those two ways. Due to the lack of units on the first number I guessed it meant (30x15)mm2.

Comment: Are we all supposed to know what a "DOI" is? (I don't.) There's a hyperlink button on the editor toolbar or you can use the syntax `[Link text](http://url.com)`.

Comment: "*This number should lead you directly to the paper.*" We use hyperlinks these days.

Comment: There may be different websites with the article available. Users may choose whichever website is more convenient for them to access and view the article.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are referring to the article [A Structural Battery and its Multifunctional Performance](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/aesr.202000093) then the dimensions appear to be incorrectly written.

> **Structural Battery Full Cell Preparation** (Section 4)

> An illustrative overview of the structural battery composite full cells manufacture is shown in Figure 1. The negative electrode was made from a CF spread tow and the positive electrode was a commercially available LFP electrode foil. **Both electrodes were cut in dimensions of 30 × 15 mm<sup>2</sup>**.

I think this is an area of **30 mm × 15 mm = (30 × 15) mm<sup>2</sup>**. Your second version is correct. Theirs is sloppy writing.

Comment: While the source's writing may be sloppy in the sense of intuition, it is mathematically sound. Units can be treated as algebraic factors and 30 mm × 15 mm = (30 × 15) mm² = 30 × 15 × mm² = 30 × (15 mm²) = 30 × 15 mm². What would actually be mathematically invalid would be an expression such as 30 ± 15 mm, which is not equal to (30 ± 15) mm = 30 mm ± 15 mm. The issue pointed out in this question is not an example of such mathematical mistakes, and only a relatively unfamiliar way of writing the information. I think "incorrect" may be too harsh a word.